# Why some classifiers are not available in WEKA?

Tags: machine-learning, weka

I have a data set and for the dataset not every classifier is available? How to I change my dataset to get, for example, J48 works for my dataset?

Thanks.

```
@relation test

@attribute SQ numeric
@attribute DH numeric
@attribute EEG1 numeric
@attribute EEG2 numeric
@attribute ECG numeric
@attribute EM numeric
@attribute FATIGUE numeric

@data
0.9,0.06,0.4,0.3,0.12,0.19,0.1
0.9,0.17,0.4,0.5,0.42,0.19,0.18
0.5,0.5,0.5,0.5,0.5,0.7,0.5
0.5,0.5,0.45,0.45,0.42,0.56,0.39
0.01,1,1,0.99,1,1,1
0.7,0.17,0.3,0.4,0.28,0.69,0.24
0.8,0.28,0.5,0.4,0.44,0.19,0.24
0.88,0.17,0.45,0.4,0.42,0.7,0.26
0.1,0.83,0.9,0.89,1,0.75,0.884
0.15,0.96,0.75,0.8,0.92,0.75,0.884
0.23,0.83,0.75,0.78,0.75,0.74,0.83
0.19,0.86,0.7,0.75,0.73,0.89,0.83
0.1,0.63,0.7,0.7,0.71,0.74,0.756
0.34,0.68,0.8,0.75,0.72,0.73,0.756
0.08,0.92,0.98,0.98,0.82,1,0.926
0.1,0.93,0.93,0.95,1,1,0.926
0.065,0.92,0.95,0.95,0.75,1,0.926
```

Answer (score 7):

`J48` is a decision tree classifier and not able to predict numeric attributes. You only have numeric attributes in your data set and therefore you can't use `J48`. If you have categorical attributes, more classifiers will be available.

Answer (score 7):

The problem is that for class attribute you have *numeric inputs*,
but *j48 needs nominal inputs*.

So, in weka, in *preprocess* tab choose *filters->unsupervised->attribute->NumericToNominal*

You are done!

Answer (score 0):

In Weka 3.7.2 and higher versions, Weka introduced a "package manager" (like a marketplace) and moved a bunch of stuff out into separately installable "packages". This was done in order to make contributions to Weka easier (and to open Weka up to the use of third-party libraries) and also to ease the maintenance burden for the Weka team. You can find the package manager in GUIChooser-->Tools.

Once the Package Manager window opens, you can see the list of packages available, Select the package you want to add into the Classifier. Then Click on the install button at the top and it will be downloaded.

If you are getting any error related to java then click on the 'Refresh Repository Cache' and again select the package and install it. This time, it will not show any error.

Packages are also browsable via the web at:
http://weka.sourceforge.net/packageMetaData/